# How to configure second level retries with distributor

Tags: nservicebus

Do I have to enable second level retries on the distributor or is it simply sufficient to enable second level retries on each worker? The timeout-manager is running on the distributor and has been disabled on each worker. My theory is that I only have to enable second level retries on the workers which will send their retries to the timeout manager address located on the distributor. The distributor is not running as master, it only runs the timeout-manager and performs message distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SLR should be on the worker nodes, as they work in conjunction with the FLR. Like you said the distributor does just that - performs message distribution. There should be no implementation / processing on the distributor. Ultimately you messages would all end up in a single error queue for all your workers if something should go wrong.